# Consulta de tablas relacionadas en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Desde ya gracias por leer mi pregunta, lo que quiero lograr es traer lo datos en una tabla la cual esta relacionada con otras dos tablas he realizado la consulta y como es normal en los campos de mis relaciones me trae los id de los campos de mis tablas foraneas lo que quiero es que me triaga el dato en vez de los id.

Mi tabla principal es:

cat_tabulator_histories esta relacionada con la tabla *cat_contract_types* y *cat_sub_contract_types*

```
   $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')->where('id_tabulator', $name)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

El resultado de esta consulta es:

id:1
name:"DAR2903"
cat_contract_type_id:1
sub_contract_type_id:2

Lo que quiero lograr:

id:1
name:"DAR2903"
cat_contract: "Contrato"
sub_contract: "subcontraro"

De ante mano muchas gracias culquier tipo de información me ayudaraia mucho mis modelos ya estan relacionados correctamente, si se requiere más información con gusto la comparto.

Comment: Prueba con `join` y actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado/investigado y el problema concreto con el que te encontraste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con DB usa Join para traer lo que nesecitas un ejemplo seria:

```
public function catos($name)
{
    $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')
        ->where('id_tabulator', $name)
        ->join('cat_contract', 'cat_contract.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.cat_contract_type_id')
        ->join('sub_contract', 'sub_contract.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.sub_contract_type_id')
        ->select('cat_tabulator_histories.id', 'cat_tabulator_histories.name', 'cat_contract.name', 'sub_contract.name')
        ->orderBy('cat_tabulator_histories.updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    return $tabulatorsHistory;
}
```

[Laravel Join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a Sergio pude generar mi consulta JOIN, les comparto el resultado por si alguien en un futuro necesita un ejemplo.

```
   $tabulatorOriginal = CatTabulator::with('subContract')->find($id);

    $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')
        ->where('id_tabulator', $tabulatorOriginal->name)
        ->join('cat_contract_types', 'cat_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.cat_contract_type_id')
        ->join('cat_sub_contract_types', 'cat_sub_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.sub_contract_type_id')
        ->select('cat_tabulator_histories.id as id', 'cat_tabulator_histories.id_tabulator as name', 'cat_tabulator_histories.base_salary_cents as salary_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.compensation_cents as compensation_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.is_active as active', 'cat_tabulator_histories.created_at as created_at', 'cat_tabulator_histories.date_active as date_active', 'cat_contract_types.name as type_contract', 'cat_sub_contract_types.name as type_subcontract')
        ->orderBy('cat_tabulator_histories.updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```